# Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-radio-button/components/radio-button

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Have added ember-radio-button to my project in ember-cli

```
version: 0.1.2
node: 0.10.24
npm: 2.1.3
```

Works fine until I build in production mode.

Then in the console I get :

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module ember-radio-button/components/radio-button
```

Using the install instructions from ember-radio-button I did:

```
npm install ember-radio-button --save-dev
```

I notice that it doesn't end up in the bower_components folder.
And bower has never heard of it.

Not sure how to get it in there or what to put in the brocfile.js

Any suggestions please?
Thanks
Vida

Comment: A link to the project or package would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You issued `npm install`, so you installed a Node package and you'll find it in `node_modules`.

You'll find a package in `bower_components` if you install it with `bower install`.

There are two ways for the component to be added in your production build.

- The add-on provides a generator that installs it from `node_modules/` to `bower_components/`, ask the add-on author for this. Example command: `ember generate ember-foobar-addon`
- Manually install the components directly into `bower_components`.

Comment: Thanks givanse. By 'manually install' do you mean just copy the folder from node_modules to bower_components?

Comment: That might be enough, but not always, sometimes add-ons create some files or download dependencies.